# find expected value of maximum of some random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, random

Let $X_1 , ..., X_n$ be independent and identically distributed continuous random variables and set and

$M=max\{k: X_{i_1} < X_{i_2} < ... < X_{i_k} , \ 1 \leq i_1 \leq i_2 \leq ... \leq i_k \leq n\}$
how I can compute $E(M)$?

Comment: @drhab I think the OP is looking at the longest increasing subsequence in the sequence $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$, e.g. if $n=4$ and the realization has values $1,2.2,-3.6,10$, then $M$ has value $3$ corresponding to $i_1=1, i_2 = 2, i_3=4$ for this realization. So, there _is_ a question here.

Comment: Closely related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2263451/15941)

Comment: @DilipSarwate Oh, I see now, and will delete my first comment. Thanks.